# Unable to find button element SELENIUM

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, automation

I have the following code for a button :

HTML CODE :

```
<div i="button" class="ui-dialog-button">
<button type="button" i-id="logout-ok">确定</button>
<button type="button" i-id="logout-cancel" class="cancel">取消</button></div>
```

CODE using Xpath as inspect :

```
element  = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[7]/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/div[2]/button[1]")).click();
```

I have try to use

```
 element = 
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button.logout-ok")).click();
```

It seems not working for , Kindly advise from my mistake . Thanks you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try with the xpath as below

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@i-id='logout-ok']")).click();
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: will accept later , due i can't accept within 10mins